# Gmail MX record Dual Nature

Tags: email, mx-record

> I have set my MX record with Google
>   Mail, but google only provide 50 email
>   address for free   is there any
>   possibility to create 50 email with
>   google and more with my own Web
>   hosting provider email server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. There's no way for MX records for a domain to distinguish between different addresses. However, if it's possible to create subdomain email addresses, you might be able to get away with creating a catch-all address in Google Apps and then setting filters to forward mail appropriately.

However, I think your best solution would really be to start paying for Google Apps if you're using it so extensively. Definitely worth it.